# Item not fetching using lookup in React Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, spfx, modern-experience, react

I am trying to fetch items using lookup but seems like it I cannot expand the child people picker column like there is a restriction in which I can't use person field by expanding the child list.
Here's my below code:

```
$.ajax({
      url: .../_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('APP_NAME')/items$select=*, BookingID/ID,BookingID/Author&$expand=BookingID`,
      type: "GET",
      dataType: "json",
      headers: {
        accept: "application/json;odata=verbose",
      },
      success: (resultData) => {
        var listdata = {
          accounting: [],
        };
        console.log(resultData.d.results);
        $.each(resultData.d.results, (index, value) => {
            console.log(value.HasPPEKit)
            listdata.accounting.push({
              Author: value.BookingID.Author,
              ID: value.BookingID.ID
            });        
        });
```

When I look in console it is giving an error but if I remove the `BookingID/Author` from filter and Author value and try to fetch only ID value using `$select=*, BookingID/ID&$expand=BookingID`  the ID value is fetching.

Is there a mistake in the API I am doing or is there any other to fetch items from 2 lists?

[and also there are some items which will not match other list. It's like I am using inner join in the list, don't focus on this line much, though].

Comment: Are you saying that BookingID is a lookup column and you want to fetch the Created By from 2nd list from where BookingID is referenced?

Comment: Right, BookingID is a lookup column looking in 2nd list and I want to fetch items from Created By column from 2nd list. Is there any way to extract the items?

Comment: It is not possible in one REST call. you need to use nested REST calls. Fetch items from 1st list and then fetch items from 2nd list based on BookingID you get from 1st call. see my answer below.

Comment: Yeah that's ok If I need to use nested REST call. So you mean fetch items from both lists and then filter out. Got it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known behavior of SharePoint.

Extending Person or Group field using lookup columns is **not supported** in SharePoint. So, you will not be able fetch or add any filter on Person or Group field from lookup list.

To get the data from 2nd list, you need to use nested REST call. You can filter the list items based on the item ID you will get from `BookingID` column.

**Supported Column Types**:

- Single line of text
- Number
- Date and Time

**Unsupported Column Types**:

- Multiple lines of text
- Currency
- Person or Group
- Calculated
- Hyperlink or Picture
- Custom Columns
- Yes/No
- Choice
- Lookup

**Microsoft official documentation**: [Create list relationships by using unique and lookup columns](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/create-list-relationships-by-using-unique-and-lookup-columns-80a3e0a6-8016-41fb-ad09-8bf16d490632)

Comment: Can you please send me code or link with proper working example of using nested call and filter. I am new to React Sharepoint.

Comment: I am not able to find any code link which matches exactly to your requirement. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39612164/can-we-query-multi-level-lookup-columns-in-sharepoint-online-using-rest-api/56236843) is one similar explanation

Comment: First call: `/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('APP_NAME')/items?$select=*, BookingID/ID&$expand=BookingID`. Then in success function of first call, you can store list item id from booking ID to one variable (say `bookingItemId`). then you can filter 2nd list like: `/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('<Second list name>')/items?$select=Title,Author/ID&$expand=Author&$filter=ID eq <bookingItemId>`